# How to merge non-fixed key json multilines into one json abstractly

Tags: python, json, parsing

If I have a heavy json file that have 30m entries like that

```json
{"id":3,"price":"231","type":"Y","location":"NY"}
{"id":4,"price":"321","type":"N","city":"BR"}
{"id":5,"price":"354","type":"Y","city":"XE","location":"CP"}
--snip--
{"id":30373779,"price":"121","type":"N","city":"SR","location":"IU"}
{"id":30373780,"price":"432","type":"Y","location":"TB"}
{"id":30373780,"price":"562","type":"N","city":"CQ"}
```

how I can only abstract the location and the city and parse it into one json like that in python:

```json
{
    "orders":{
        3:{
            "location":"NY"
        },
        4:{
            "city":"BR"
        },
        5:{
            "city":"XE",
            "location":"CP"
        },
        30373779:{
            "city":"SR",
            "location":"IU"
        },
        30373780:{
            "location":"TB"
        },
        30373780:{
            "city":"CQ"
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: beatufy the syntax is not necessary.

Comment: Let start by pointing out that this (the input) is not `json`, but looks like `ndjson`/`jsonlines` format (i.e. you need to read/parse each line separately or use convince library for that). Then, ask for your code so far ([mre]) and what specific problem with your code do you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input file is actually in `jsonlines` format, then you can read each line, extract the `city` and `location` keys from the dict and then append those to a new dict:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

orders = { 'orders' : defaultdict(dict) }
with open('orders.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        o = json.loads(line)
        id = o['id']
        if 'location' in o:
            orders['orders'][id]['location'] = o['location'] 
        if 'city' in o:
            orders['orders'][id]['city'] = o['city'] 

print(orders)
```

Output for your sample data (note it has two `30373780` id values, so the values get merged into one dict):

```
{
    "orders": {
        "3": {
            "location": "NY"
        },
        "4": {
            "city": "BR"
        },
        "5": {
            "location": "CP",
            "city": "XE"
        },
        "30373779": {
            "location": "IU",
            "city": "SR"
        },
        "30373780": {
            "location": "TB",
            "city": "CQ"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've said that your file is pretty big and you probably don't want to keep all entries in memory here is the way to consume source file line by line and write output immediately:

```py
import json

with open(r"in.jsonp") as i_f, open(r"out.json", "w") as o_f:
    o_f.write('{"orders":{')
    for i in i_f:
        i_obj = json.loads(i)
        o_f.write(f'{i_obj["id"]}:')
        o_obj = {}
        if location := i_obj.get("location"):
            o_obj["location"] = location
        if city := i_obj.get("city"):
            o_obj["city"] = city
        json.dump(o_obj, o_f)
        o_f.write(",")
    o_f.write('}}')
```

It will generate semi-valid JSON object in same format you've provided in your question.